# django local variable referenced before assignment

Tags: python, django

Im creating a django application but im unsure of what im doing wrong. I keep getting the error "local variable 'sigtracker' referenced before assignment" this is the code being referenced by the error. I know it has to do with the form validation but im unsure of what im doing wrong.

```
@login_required
@permission_required('auth.signiture_management')
def add_signiture_view(request):
logger.debug("add_signiture_view called by user %s" % request.user)
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = SignitureForm(request.POST)
    logger.debug("Request type POST contains form valid: %s" %     form.is_valid())
    if form.is_valid():
        # handle valid form
        sigtracker = sigtracker()
        sigtracker.ident = form.cleaned_data['ident']
        sigtracker.system = form.cleaned_data['system']
        sigtracker.name = form.cleaned_data['name']
        sigtracker.signiture_type = form.cleaned_data['signiture type']
        sigtracker.status = form.cleaned_data['status']
        sigtracker.save()
        logger.info("Created new signiture in %s at %s by user %s" % (sigtracker.system, request.user))
        return HttpResponseRedirect("/sigtracker/")
else:
    logger.debug("Returning new SignitureForm")
    form = SignitureForm()

render_items = {'form': form}

return render_to_response('registered/addsigniture.html', render_items, context_instance=RequestContext(request))

Environment:


Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://redacted/add_signiture/

Django Version: 1.6.5
Python Version: 2.7.5
Installed Applications:
('django.contrib.admin',
 'django.contrib.auth',
 'django.contrib.contenttypes',
 'django.contrib.sessions',
 'django.contrib.messages',
 'django.contrib.staticfiles',
 'django.contrib.humanize',
 'django_evolution',
 'djcelery',
 'celerytask',
 'bootstrapform',
 'authentication',
 'portal',
 'registration',
 'services',
 'eveonline',
 'groupmanagement',
 'hrapplications',
 'timerboard',
 'srp',
 'sigtracker')
Installed Middleware:
('django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
 'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
 'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware')




 Traceback:
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
  112.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  22.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/contrib/auth/decorators.py" in _wrapped_view
  22.                 return view_func(request, *args, **kwargs)
File "/home/allianceserver/allianceauth/sigtracker/views.py" in add_signiture_view
  46.             sigtracker = sigtracker()

Exception Type: UnboundLocalError at /add_signiture/
Exception Value: local variable 'sigtracker' referenced before assignment
```

Comment: Post the full traceback and alert us to which specific lines are referenced in the error. Also, your indentation is wrong under the function. If it is that way in your actual code, that may be your issue.

Comment: I expect that you have sigtracker class. If that is the case you might not want to call the variable the same as the class, it might be confusing the parser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is on this line

```
sigtracker = sigtracker()
```

You have imported your model class `sigtracker()` outside of the view function. In Python, it is not possible to reference this class inside the function, and assign it to the same local variable name.

The quickest fix would be to rename the `sigtracker` instance to something else, e.g. `st`:

```
    st = sigtracker()
    st.ident = form.cleaned_data['ident']
    st.system = form.cleaned_data['system']
    st.name = form.cleaned_data['name']
    st.signiture_type = form.cleaned_data['signiture type']
    st.status = form.cleaned_data['status']
    st.save()
    logger.info("Created new signiture in %s at %s by user %s" % (st.system, request.user))
```

It is confusing to try to use `sigtracker` to refer to the model class and model instances. It is recommended to use capitalised names for your models, e.g. `SigTracker` (this is a pep8 recommendation for Python classes in general).

That way, you can easily tell the difference between the model `SigTracker` and the model instance `sigtracker`.

If you rename the model to `SigTracker`, make sure to update your imports and code everywhere you use it.

Comment: It would be interesting to note that this would happen with any class named the same as a local variable and is not something specific to a django model.

Comment: @tdelaney I've rewritten the answer to be less Django specific. As you say, it's a regular Python error.

Comment: Thank you that was the issue cant believe i missed it